# Assign returned JSON to localstorage via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

This seems so simple but has really stumped me..basically I am trying to assign valid JSON being returned from an MVC 4 action (allows the inserting of a user) via an AJAX call. The JSON is being returned successfully but I cannot parse the JSON on the client side so that I can assign the variables to local storage. If someone could please show me where I am going wrong I would be very grateful as I have been stuck on this for one whole day, thanks.

**JSON**

{
    "Success": true,
    "user": {
        "UserId": 7,
        "Name": "Bob",
        "Email": "bob@email.com",
        "Occupation": "Dev",
        "Country": "UK",
        "RegistrationNumber": "B001",
        "UserDate": "/Date(1401840000000)/",
        "Results": null
    }
}

**MVC 4 Action**

```
   [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.InsertUser(user);
            repository.Save();

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                //success
                return Json(new { Success = true, user }); 

                // no success
                return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Error" }); 

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);

    }
```

**AJAX**
    //Register
  self.create = function () {

```
if (User.Name() != "" && User.Email() != "" && User.Occupation() != "") {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/Create',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: ko.toJSON(User),
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.Success) {

                //NOTE the following not working
                var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(data);
    localStorage.setItem("UserId", dataToStore.UserId);

               //NOTE the following alert outputs an undefined message?

                alert(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserId")))

    //NOTE the following not being assigned either?

                localStorage.setItem("Name", data.Name);
                localStorage.setItem("Email", data.Email);
                localStorage.setItem("Occupation", data.Occupation);
                localStorage.setItem("Country", data.Country);
                localStorage.setItem("RegistrationNumber", data.RegistrationNumber);

                //testing output
                 viewModel.UserId(data.UserId);

                //redirect to questions
              //  window.location = "QnA.html"
            }
            else {
                viewModel.UserId("Error user not created, please try again.");
            }
        },
    }).fail(
        function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
            console.log('fail');
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(err);
        });

} else {
    alert('Please enter all fields');
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing user data you have to access like follows;

```
data.user.Name
data.user.Email
```

And set the Json request behavior when you return JSON as follows;

```
return Json(new { Success = true, user } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmgW/)**

Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant that works Saranga. Really appreciate the help from everyone who posted responses to this post!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly when u r returning json result update it as follow

```
 return Json(new { Success = true, user } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
 return Json(new { Success = false, Message = "Error" } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet});
```